# How to optimize Mean Square Displacement for several particles in two dimensions in python?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, multidimensional-array, vectorization

I want to calculate the mean square displacement for several particles, defined as:
[image]

where `i` is the index for the particle, `Dt` is the time interval, `t` is the time, and `vec(x)` is the position of the particles in two dimensions. We do an average for all possible times `t`.

I have managed to implement it with numpy. Note that `pos` is a `np.array` with three axis: `(particles, time, coordinate)`.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

#Initialize data
np.random.seed(1)
nTime = 10**4
nParticles = 3
pos = np.zeros((nParticles, nTime, 2)) #Axis: particles, times, coordinates
for t in range(1, nTime):
    pos[:, t, :] = pos[:, t-1, :] + ( np.random.random((nParticles, 2)) - 0.5)

#MSD calculation
def MSD_direct(pos):
    Dt_r = np.arange(1, pos.shape[1]-1)
    MSD = np.empty((nParticles, len(Dt_r)))
    dMSD = np.empty((nParticles,len(Dt_r)))
    for k, Dt in enumerate(Dt_r):
        SD = np.sum((pos[:, Dt:,:] - pos[:, 0:-Dt,:])**2, axis = -1)
        MSD[:,k] = np.mean( SD , axis = 1)
        dMSD[:,k] = np.std( SD, axis = 1 ) / np.sqrt(SD.shape[1])

    return Dt_r, MSD, dMSD

start_time = time.time()
Dt_r, MSD_d, dMSD_d = MSD_direct(pos)
print("MSD_direct -- Time: %s s\n" % (time.time() - start_time))

#Plots
plt.figure()
for i in range(nParticles):
    plt.plot(pos[i,:,0])    
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('x')
plt.savefig('pos_x.png', dpi = 300)

plt.figure()
for i in range(nParticles):
    plt.plot(pos[i,:,1])    
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.savefig('pos_y.png', dpi = 300)

plt.figure()
for i in range(nParticles):
    plt.fill_between(Dt_r, MSD_d[i,:]+dMSD_d[i,:], MSD_d[i,:] - dMSD_d[i,:], alpha = 0.5)
    plt.plot(Dt_r, MSD_d[i,:])
plt.xlabel('Dt')
plt.ylabel('MSD')
plt.savefig('MSD.png', dpi = 300)
```

**Output**:

`MSD_direct -- Time: 7.793087720870972 s`

[image]
[image]
[image]

However, I would like to **optimize this code if possible**. There is *still* a loop for `Dt`, I do not know how could I remove it and vectorize the program fully using *numpy*.

---

I also rewrote the calculation using *numba*, managing around a **factor two** of improvement from the previous code. I wonder if it is still possible to further improve it.

```py
import numba as nb
@nb.jit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def MSD_numba(pos):
    Dt_r = np.arange(1, pos.shape[1]-1)
    MSD = np.empty((nParticles, len(Dt_r)))
    dMSD = np.empty((nParticles,len(Dt_r)))
    for i in nb.prange(nParticles):  
        for Dt in Dt_r:
            SD = (pos[i, Dt:, 0] - pos[i, 0:-Dt, 0])**2 + (pos[i, Dt:, 1] - pos[i, 0:-Dt, 1])**2
            MSD[i, Dt-1] = np.mean( SD )
            dMSD[i, Dt-1] = np.std( SD ) / np.sqrt(len(SD)) 
    return Dt_r, MSD, dMSD

start_time = time.time()
Dt_r, MSD_n, dMSD_n = MSD_numba(pos)
print("MSD_numba -- Time: %s s" % (time.time() - start_time))
print("MSD_numba -- All close to MSD_direct: %r\n" %(np.allclose(MSD_n, MSD_d) )  )
```

**Output:**

```
MSD_numba -- Time: 4.520232915878296 s
MSD_numba -- All close to MSD_direct: True
```

---

Note: this type of question has been asked in several posts already, but they use different definitions ([Mean square displacement python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31264591/12131616), [Mean squared displacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36372980/mean-squared-displacement), [Mean square displacement for n-dim matrix python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63989886/12131616)), they do not have an answer ([Mean square displacement in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62119843/12131616)), they just use one particle ([Computing mean square displacement using python and FFT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34222272/12131616), [Mean square displacement of a 1d random walk in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65212541/12131616)), they use pandas ([Vectorized calculation of Mean Square Displacement in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50194706/12131616), [Speedup MSD calculation in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32988269/12131616)), etc.

Comment: I am prette sure this line `np.linalg.norm(pos[:, Dt:] - pos[:, 0:-Dt], axis = -1)**2` has two errors: 1) why square norm? there is no squaring in the definition apart from norm that does the squaring. 2) `pos[:, Dt:] - pos[:, 0:-Dt]` should be something like `np.diff(pos[:, Dt:])`

Comment: @dankal444 I don't understand why do you believe I calculated wrong the MSD. The line `np.linalg.norm(pos[:, Dt:] - pos[:, 0:-Dt], axis = -1)**2` is literally the definition I showed at the beginning of my post, it is also numerically equal to `np.sum((pos[:, Dt:] - pos[:, 0:-Dt])**2, axis = -1)`, in case you find it clearer. Also, why use `np.diff`? We are not doing differences from consecutive elements of the array, but differences at intervals `Dt`.

Comment: Maybe what it confused you is that `pos` has three axis: (particle, time, coordinate). When I do the norm is respect the coordinate axis, because the vectors are in two dimensions.

Comment: I see now I was wrong. Nevertheless, as you said, `np.sum((pos[:, Dt:] - pos[:, 0:-Dt])**2, axis = -1)` is equivalent and **faster**, I found this strange that you take square root (in norm) and immediately square those numbers  - that led me to thinking there must be some error.

Comment: If you run your code more than once, add `use_cache=True`  option to `@nb.jit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)` so that compilation will not be repeated next run. When I run the same script second time I get like 6x faster run

Comment: Just FYI: multiprocessing but without numba gave me about the same timings as your numba code but without performance loss (no need for `fastmath`)

Comment: @dankal444 you are right, it is a bit faster using the squared sum, I changed now the code from the question. Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting the answer from [Computing mean square displacement using python and FFT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34222272/12131616) that uses FFT transforms, I managed to do this calculation faster by **two orders of magnitude**.

---

### Generalized function for any  n dimensional array

This function assumes `pos` to be any n dimensional array, where you just need to specify the axes of time and of the coordinates (x,y). It returns the mean square displacement associated to all particles in `pos`.

```py
def MSD_fft_ax(pos, axis_time, axis_coord):
    nTime=pos.shape[axis_time]        

    S2 = np.sum (  np.fft.ifft( np.abs(np.fft.fft(pos, n=2*nTime, axis = axis_time))**2, axis = axis_time ).take(range(nTime), axis = axis_time).real, axis = axis_coord )
    
    D=np.square(pos).sum(axis=axis_coord)

    if axis_coord % pos.ndim < axis_time % pos.ndim: axis_time -= 1

    shape_t = [nTime if ax==axis_time % D.ndim else 1 for ax, s in enumerate(D.shape)]
    shape_non_t = [1 if ax==axis_time % D.ndim else s for ax, s in enumerate(D.shape)]

    D=np.append(D, np.zeros( shape_non_t ), axis = axis_time)
    S1 = ( 2 * np.sum(D, axis = axis_time).reshape(shape_non_t) - np.cumsum( np.insert(D.take(np.arange(0,nTime), axis=axis_time), 0, 0, axis = axis_time) + np.flip(D, axis = axis_time), axis = axis_time ) ).take(np.arange(0,nTime), axis = axis_time) 

    MSD = ( S1-2*S2 ) / ( nTime-np.arange(nTime).reshape(shape_t) )

    Dt_r = np.arange(1, nTime-1)
    MSD = MSD.take(Dt_r, axis = axis_time)
    return Dt_r, MSD

start_time = time.time()
Dt_r, MSD_fax = MSD_fft_ax(pos, axis_time = 1, axis_coord=-1)
print("MSD_fft_ax -- Time: %s s" % (time.time() - start_time))
print("MSD_fft_ax -- All close to MSD_direct: %r\n" %(np.allclose(MSD_fax, MSD_d) )  )
```

**Output:**

```py
MSD_direct -- Time: 2.1434285640716553 s

MSD_numba -- Time: 1.532573938369751 s
MSD_numba -- All close to MSD_direct: True

MSD_fft_ax -- Time: 0.009054422378540039 s
MSD_fft_ax -- All close to MSD_direct: True
```

---

### Function for an array with shape: `(particles, time, coordinate)`.

For a better understanding I include the particular case where `pos` is an array of shape `(particles, time, coordinate)`:

```py
def MSD_fft(pos):
    nTime=pos.shape[1]        

    S2 = np.sum ( np.fft.ifft( np.abs(np.fft.fft(pos, n=2*nTime, axis = -2))**2, axis = -2  )[:,:nTime,:].real , axis = -1 ) / (nTime-np.arange(nTime)[None,:] )

    D=np.square(pos).sum(axis=-1)
    D=np.append(D, np.zeros((pos.shape[0], 1)), axis = -1)
    S1 = ( 2 * np.sum(D, axis = -1)[:,None] - np.cumsum( np.insert(D[:,0:-1], 0, 0, axis = -1) + np.flip(D, axis = -1), axis = -1 ) )[:,:-1] / (nTime - np.arange(nTime)[None,:] )

    MSD = S1-2*S2

    Dt_r = np.arange(1, pos.shape[1]-1)
    MSD = MSD[:,Dt_r]
    return Dt_r, MSD

start_time = time.time()
Dt_r, MSD_f = MSD_fft(pos)
print("MSD_fft -- Time: %s s" % (time.time() - start_time))
print("MSD_fft -- All close to MSD_direct: %r\n" %(np.allclose(MSD_f, MSD_d) )  )
```

**Output:**

```
MSD_fft -- Time: 0.007384061813354492 s
MSD_fft -- All close to MSD_direct: True
```